# Is this possible to test push notification without developer ID?

Tags: ios, push-notification

After xcode 7 beta version, I can install application on real device without developer ID. But, can we do the same for `push notification`. or we have to apply for developer ID? If there is a method, please refer link.

Comment: You must have to opt developer id from apple. In no way you can do.

Comment: As we can test app on real device without developer id after xcode 7 beta .Thats why I asked  this question ?

Comment: You need to generate push notification certificate of your app in member centre at [developer site](https://developer.apple.com) to enable notification. Without a valid ID, you won't be able to do that. Hence, answer is NO.

Comment: Ok  thank you @GellertLee

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to use Apple push notifications you'll need to generate a certificate for your app in the member's center which can only be accessed if you have a current membership to the Apple Developer Program.